# Save ArCore session and view it again even when not present at the same location

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to use the ARCore library to place objects in the real world location and want to just view the exact same view even when I am not present at the same location in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do either one of two things:

- capture and record the view from your device display when you are using ARCore and then view again the recording of the screen view you saw at the time
- capture the entire 360 degree world you are in at the time so that you can recreate it and move around in it, having some ARCore renderable at the place you put them when you did the capture, so you can walk up to them and around them etc.

The first case is relatively straightforward and ArCore provides some instructions to manage this:

- https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/video-recording

The second case would require you to record the 360 degree world and also to have the ability to move around in that recording with what is usually called '6 degrees of freedom' 6DOF - similar to the way you can move around a first person video game.

Recording 6DOF videos is a complex technology in itself, typically requiring multiple cameras and quite a bit of post processing and I am not aware of anything that integrates this with ARCore at this time. It tends to be still at the research stage in many cases - e.g.:

- https://v-sense.scss.tcd.ie/research/6dof/